# Laravel 5.2 not loading any assets

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

None of my assets are loading in my project I've been using a virtual host and it won't load them from the resources/assets/js folder and I've also tried using localhost:8000 does anyone know why?

Comment: Files available for access must be inside the `public` directory, or at least have a symbolic link from somewhere inside the `public` directory to other directories, such as `resources`.

Answer (score 1):

scripts or any related files that should be accessed via url should be stored in the `public` directory